# How to make an array of element in ruby from a string

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I have a giant string as follow **obtained from Nokogiri** inside a `<script>` tag:

```
   ....com\\/shop\",\"url\":\"?search=espadrille&options=reserve-eligible\",\"slug\":\"options\",\"order\":null,\"matchesMainFilter\":null,\"name\":\"Reserve Eligible\",\"type\":\"options\",\"identifier\":\"reserve-eligible\"}],\"title\":\"Options\",\"identifier\":\"options\",\"remove_url\":\"?search=espadrille\",\"classification\":\"\",\"view_all_url\":\"\",\"count\":\"\",\"slug\":\"\"},{\"children\":[{\"id\":95,\"children\":[{\"id\":150,\"children\":[],\"count\":1,\"applied\":false,\"removeUrl\":\"https:\\/\\/www.fashionphile.com\\/shop\",\"url\":\"?brands=chanel&chanel=lambskin&search=espadrille\",\"slug\":\"lambskin\",\"order\":null,\"matchesMainFilter\":false,\"name\":\"Lambskin\",\"type\":\"brand\"}],\"count\":7,\"applied\":false,\"removeUrl\":\"https:\\/\\/www.fashionphile.com\\/shop\",\"url\":\"?brands=chanel&search=espadrille\",\"slug\":\"chanel\",\"order\":null,\"matchesMainFilter\":false,\"name\":\"Chanel\",\"type\":\"brand\",\"identifier\":\"chanel\"},{\"id\":98,\"children\":[],\"count\":1,\"applied\":false,\"removeUrl\":\"https:\\/\\/www.fashionphile.com\\/shop\",\"url\":\"?brands=louboutin&search=espadrille\",\"slug\":\"louboutin\",\"order\":null,\"matchesMainFilter\":false,\"name\":\"Christian Louboutin\",\"type\":\"brand\",\"identifier\":\"christian-louboutin\"},{\"id\":103,\"children\":[],\"count\":3,\"applied\":false,\"removeUrl\":\"https:\\/\\/www.fashionphile.com\\/shop\",\"url\":\"?brands=gucci&search=espadrille\",\"slug\":\"gucci\",\"order\":null,\"matchesMainFilter\":false,\"name\":\"Gucci\",\"type\":\"brand\",\"identifier\":\"gucci\"},{\"id\":104,\"children\":[],\"count\":1,\"applied\":false,\"removeUrl\":\"https:\\/\\/www.fashionphile.com\\/shop\",\"url\":\"?brands=hermes&search=espadrille\",\"slug\":\"hermes\",\"order\":null,\"matchesMainFilter\":false,\"name\":\"Hermes\",\"type\":\"brand\",\"identifier\":\"hermes\"},{\"id\":107,\"children\":[{\"id\":132,\"children\":[],\"count\":1,\"applied\":false,\"removeUrl\":\"https:\\/\\/www.fashionphile.com\\/shop\",\"url\":\"?brands=louis-vuitton&louis-vuitton=louis-vuitton-monogram&search=espadrille\",\"slug\":\"louis-vuitton-monogram\",\"order\":null,\"matchesMainFilter\":false,\"name\":\"Monogram\",\"type\":\"brand\"}],\"count\":2,\"applied\":false,\"removeUrl\":\"https:\\/\\/www.fashionphile.com\\/shop\",\"url\":\"?brands=louis-vuitton&search=espadrille\",\"slug\":\"louis-vuitton\",\"order\":null,\"matchesMainFilter\":false,\"name\":\"Louis Vuitton\",\"type\":\"brand\",\"identifier\":\"louis-vuitton\"},{\"id\":115,\"children\":[],\"count\":4,\"applied\":false,\"removeUrl\":\"https:\\/\\/www.fashionphile.com\\/shop\",\"url\":\"?brands=valentino&search=espadrille\",\"slug\":\"valentino\",\"order...
```

I want to find a way to get all the `brands=xxxxxx` inside an array like `["chanel", "LV"]` or maybe a hash `{brand1: "chanel", brand2: "LV"}`.

--- EDIT ---

And how can I access `<meta itemprop=\"brand\" content=\"Chanel\">` and associate it with its `<span class=\"sale-price\" itemprop=\"price\" content=\"595.00\">`in an array or hash like this:

hash = {chanel: "200", LV: "100"}

Here is the script without data to make it smaller:

```
<script>
    var bootstrappedShopResults = {"products":"<div class=\"container-fluid\">\n    <div class=\"product-flex\">\n            <\/div>\n<\/div>\n","meta":{"pagination":"","total":0,"itemsFrom":null,"itemsTo":null},"aggregations":[{"children":[],"title":"Price","identifier":"price","remove_url":"?","classification":"","view_all_url":"","count":"","slug":""},{"children":[],"title":"Options","identifier":"options","remove_url":"?","classification":"","view_all_url":"","count":"","slug":""},{"children":[],"title":"Brands","identifier":"brands","remove_url":"?","classification":"","view_all_url":"","count":"","slug":""},{"children":[],"title":"Condition","identifier":"condition","remove_url":"?","classification":"","view_all_url":"","count":"","slug":""}],"parameters":{"pageSize":180,"sort":"date-desc","search":"espadrille.json"},"appliedFilters":[],"mainFilter":null,"pageTitle":"Shop Pre owned Designer Handbags | Used Designer Bags | Fashionphile","metaDescription":"Fashionphile offers a wide selection of pre-owned designer handbags and accessories. Add quality, used designer bags and more to your collection today!","removeSearchUrl":"?pageSize=180&sort=date-desc"};
</script>
```

Comment: Is that the whole string? I am asking because it looks like JSON and if it was then I would suggest using a JSON parser, but at the start and at the end there seems to be missing something. Where is this string coming from?

Comment: I second what @spickermann said. This looks like you posted malformed JSON. If that is not the entire string then it is likely the true string properly formed JSON and would be fairly simple to handle with a JSON parser.

Comment: its from inside a script tag from scraping a web site, I tried to use a parser but I was told its not possible because I get a big string so I cannot just convert it to json. Do you think you can do it ? I would prefer that way if its possible.

Comment: @Antoine what are you using for scraping? A few notes: 1)page scraping is tough because the page can change at any time. 2) libraries like `nokogiri` offer css and xpath selectors which can be much more targeted than string selection. 3) how you went about obtaining this data is paramount to your question as it might lead to far better solutions than your original question of segmenting a string.

Comment: yes I used Nokogiri I just edited the question to also add the ruby object I am expecting.

Comment: because page can change at any time I would like to find a reliable way to access the data the same way I would with css or xpath event though I am dealing with a string. is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can scan with a regex, like so:

```
brands_array = string.scan(/brands=([^&]+)/)
```

Which will provide:

```
[["chanel"], ["chanel"], ["louboutin"], ["gucci"], ["hermes"], ["louis-vuitton"], ["louis-vuitton"], ["valentino"]]
```

If you don't wanna repeated, just call uniq:

```
brands_array = string.scan(/brands=([^&]+)/).uniq
```

This will return:

```
[["chanel"], ["louboutin"], ["gucci"], ["hermes"], ["louis-vuitton"], ["valentino"]]
```

Comment: thanks. And how can I access <meta itemprop=\"brand\" content=\"Chanel\"> and associate it with its <span class=\"sale-price\" itemprop=\"price\" content=\"595.00\">in an array or hash ?

Comment: do you know of a way for me to know what regex I need for my different need of fetching the data ?

Answer (score 2):

```
str.gsub(/(?<=\bbrands=)[^&]+/).to_a
  #=> ["chanel", "chanel", "louboutin", "gucci", "hermes", "louis-vuitton",
  #    "louis-vuitton", "valentino"]
```

Tack on `.uniq` if desired.

This makes use of the fact that [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) returns an enumerator when used without a block.

Comment: thanks. how can I access <meta itemprop=\"brand\" content=\"Chanel\"> and associate it with its <span class=\"sale-price\" itemprop=\"price\" content=\"595.00\">in an array or hash ?

Comment: That's a different question. You should only ask one question at a time. I suggest you roll-back your question to before you added the EDIT and then post a separate question. (The meaning of your EDIT is not clear to me, btw.) When doing so see if you can reduce the length of your string as much as you can. It's also helpful to a assign a variable to each input to examples, e.g., `str = 'com\\/shop\",\"url\":\"?search...'`). That way the variable can be referenced in answers and comments without having to define it. Lastly, pleased show the desired result (a Ruby object) for each example.